# Issues with connecting screen component to more than one reducer

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am fairly new to react native and I was wondering if it is possible for a single screen component to be connected to multiple reducers within the mapstatetoProp function. Please note that I am using redux for state management.

Comment: With mapStateToProps, you access to the whole state of your app and with mapDispatchToProps, you can dispatch every action that you defined in your app. Please tell us more clearly about your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In that case i guess i would have to see how  can i dispatch multiple actions within the mapstatetoprops method. Any code example of this available ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps.

```
// Here you can import multiple actions for multiple reducers
import ProductActions from '...'
import BasketActions from '...'

class MyScreen extends Component () {
   _addUser (user) {
     this.props.addUser(user)
   }
   _addProduct (product) {
     this.props.addProduct(product)
   }

   render () {
     // Here you can use all props that you mapped in mapStateToProps
   }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addProduct: (product) => dispatch(ProductActions.add(product)),
  addUser: (user) => dispatch(BasketActions.setInstruction(user))
})

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    products: state.products,
    users: basketItemsSelector(state, restaurant.id)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyScreen)
```